# Write boost::dynamic_bitset to file

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I'm implementing Shannon-Fano coding algorithm and I want to output symbol codes as bits.

For example, in the following code I read the symbols from input file (`fin` stream) line by line, fill the `std::string` with symbol codes (from `std::map<unsigned short, std::string> symbolCodes`) formed by the algorithm, then construct the `boost::dynamic_bitset` with the contents of `currentOutString`. Then I have tried to output the bitset, but in the output file each "true" or "false" value from the bitset takes up 1 byte instead of 1 bit.

```
if (fin.is_open() && fout.is_open()) {
    std::string currentInString;
    std::string currentOutString;

    while (getline(fin, currentInString)) {
        boost::dynamic_bitset<> bitSet;
        for (auto & ref : currentInString) {
            currentOutString += symbolCodes[ref];
        }

        for (auto & ref : currentOutString) {
            if (ref == '0') bitSet.push_back(0);
            if (ref == '1') bitSet.push_back(1);
        }
        fout << bitSet;

        bitSet.clear();
        currentOutString.erase();
    }
}
```

`fout` stream is opened in `std::ios_base::binary` mode. For instance, I have word "file" and the codes are `e: 00, f: 01, i: 10, l: 11`. How do I output my bitset, so output file takes up 8 bits instead of 8 bytes?

Thank you in advance for your help and sorry for possible language mistakes.

Comment: Does [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/example/example3.cpp) help?

Comment: @ulidtko, unfortunately, it doesn't. This example doesn't say anything about file output, just the console one.

Comment: Conceptually, console isn't that different from a file. Your problem was with `iostream` argument formatting (converting bytes to strings in a way you don't want), not actually with files. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not the `dynamic_bitset`'s fault; it's `iostream`'s.

The following code prints

> ```
> 123
> ----.
> ```

to the `cout`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost;

    auto bitset = dynamic_bitset<>(32, 0x0a333231); // "123\n" in little endian
    bitset.append(0x2d2d2d2d); // "----"
    bitset.append(0x0a2e); // ".\n"
    // bitset.size() is at least 96 here

    auto ulong_mask = dynamic_bitset<>(bitset.size(), 0xFFFFFFFFul);
    while(bitset.any()) {
        unsigned long ulong = (bitset & ulong_mask).to_ulong();
        cout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ulong), sizeof(ulong));

        bitset >>= 32;
    }
}
```

Note the use of `cout.write()` instead of `operator <<`. It outputs bytes *as-is*, without any formatting and conversion to ASCII strings (think of `itoa()` or something similar).

---

One more point: because `dynamic_bitset` doesn't provide contiguous storage guarantees and/or access, we must read out big bitsets by chunks, preferably of larger size; e.g. `unsigned long`.

On some architectures, `sizeof(unsigned long)` will be 8, so we can actually use a larger `ulong_mask` ([`ULONG_MAX`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) would do), and shift by `(8 * sizeof(unsigned long))` accordingly. Use that. (32 above is hardcoded for clarity of illustration).

Comment: Uhm, I understood, `cout.write()` has to be used. How do I use it in my case? Do I need that `ulong_mask`? `unsigned long ulong = bitSet.to_ulong(); fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ulong), sizeof(ulong));` outputs 8 bytes.

Comment: @WildSpirit, I think you really have to use `to_ulong()` to output a large bitset chunk-by-chunk. That's because the backing storage of `dynamic_bitset` is unspecified, and it doesn't guarantee (and/or publicly provide access to) contiguous storage for its bits. I'll update the answer to make the point clear.